# Extra line added after pasted a line that was previously copied using CTRL + C

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

How can I disable this behaviour:

I copy a line moving the caret on it `CTRL + C`.

Then I paste it where I need it using `CTRL + V`.

For some reason the IDE is adding and extra line after I paste the copied line.

This doesn't happen if I `select the code` and then use the combination `CTRL+C - CTRL+V`

Comment: I think it is normal behavior cause ctrl+c copy whole line and line ending simbol

Comment: It's very annoying because I have to remove that extra line every time I paste a line. If I need an extra line I will just press *Enter*.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/basic-editing.html
there are shortcuts that you might find usefull. For your particular problem i would press 'home' then 'shift+end' to select line w/o end line symbols

Comment: All this work to not include that extra line. It's a lot of wasted time.

Comment: I found a really good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I still didn't find how to disable the described behaviour.

I found how to copy lines or even a block using a *Keyboard Shortcut* the way Eclipse was doing it without adding any extra new line.

**Setting** > **Keymap** > **DuplicateLines**

**DuplicateLines** also copy a block of code and position it on a new line and not on the same line like **Duplicate Line or Block** does.